# debmirror keeps hanging trying to download packages

Tags: apt, package-management, debmirror

I have a local distribution mirror which I've set for the supported LTS versions of Ubuntu (18.04, 20.04 and 22.04). But when I run debmirror to sync with gb.archive.ubuntu.com it keeps stopping at a package and not going any further. If I stop and restart debmirror it will stop at the same package again. If I manually download the package and restart debmirror, it will move on but then stop at another package. I can't see anything special about the offending packages. They aren't necessarily particularly large. But it's doing my head in! Been trying to get the full set of packages for almost a week now. It's been running fine up till now, but this started from when I dropped 16.04 and added 22.04.

Comment: You probably need to add some more details that will allow someone to help you.

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with `debmirror`, so I wouldn't know what to look for. Hopefully someone else knows..

Comment: Unfortunately, nor am I! It's system I inherited and generally just works.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Debmirror

It has a script which I use regularly to maintain an ubuntu mirror using debmirror at my workplace. You are using gb.archive.ubuntu.com but there the script just specifies archive.ubuntu.com and it works (been using it for 2 years now). I download the packages for amd64 only using http (takes about a day or so) and then I use rsync to correct any failures in downloading using http.

For your convenience I have copy pasted below the script from the above link:

```
#### Start script to automate building of Ubuntu mirror #####
## THE NEXT LINE IS NEEDED THE REST OF THE LINES STARTING WITH A # CAN BE DELETED

#!/bin/bash

## Setting variables with explanations.

#
# Don't touch the user's keyring, have our own instead
#
export GNUPGHOME=/opt/UbuntuMirror/mirrorkeyring

# Arch=         -a      # Architecture. For Ubuntu can be i386, powerpc or amd64.
# sparc, only starts in dapper, it is only the later models of sparc.
# For multiple  architecture, use ",". like "i386,amd64"

arch=amd64

# Minimum Ubuntu system requires main, restricted
# Section=      -s      # Section (One of the following - main/restricted/universe/multiverse).
# You can add extra file with $Section/debian-installer. ex: main/debian-installer,universe/debian-installer,multiverse/debian-installer,restricted/debian-installer
#
section=main,restricted,universe,multiverse

# Release=      -d      # Release of the system (, focal ), and the -updates and -security ( -backports can be added if desired)
# List of updated releases in: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases
# List of sort codenames used: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/

release=focal,focal-security,focal-updates

# Server=       -h      # Server name, minus the protocol and the path at the end
# CHANGE "*" to equal the mirror you want to create your mirror from. au. in Australia  ca. in Canada.
# This can be found in your own /etc/apt/sources.list file, assuming you have Ubuntu installed.
#
server=archive.ubuntu.com

# Dir=          -r      # Path from the main server, so http://my.web.server/$dir, Server dependant
#
inPath=/ubuntu

# Proto=        --method=       # Protocol to use for transfer (http, ftp, hftp, rsync)
# Choose one - http is most usual the service, and the service must be available on the server you point at.
# For some "rsync" may be faster.
proto=http

# Outpath=              # Directory to store the mirror in
# Make this a full path to where you want to mirror the material.
#
outPath=/opt/UbuntuMirror/ubuntu-mirror

# The --nosource option only downloads debs and not deb-src's
# The --progress option shows files as they are downloaded
# --source \ in the place of --no-source \ if you want sources also.
# --nocleanup  Do not clean up the local mirror after mirroring is complete. Use this option to keep older repository
# Start script
#
debmirror       -a $arch \
                --no-source \
                -s $section \
                -h $server \
                -d $release \
                -r $inPath \
                --progress \
                --method=$proto \
                $outPath


#### End script to automate building of Ubuntu mirror ####
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's a script we're already using. Actually, the problem is solved but I can't remember what the resolution was. I think it just started working again, but might have been a size restriction in our proxy.